# Как с помощью php обратиться к папке под определенным пользователем?

Tags: php

Есть сетевая папка, для папки создана роль с доступом для чтения и записи. Как через код обратиться к этой папке под определенной ролью? Операционная система - Windows

Comment: В php нет понятия "служебная папка", "служебный пользователь". Пиши подробно условия начиная и ОС. Исправляй вопрос пока не закрыли.

Comment: @seVlad понятно, а какие понятия есть php?

Comment: Копайте в сторону утилиты 'runas'. Запускаете ее из `php`, а с ее помощью еще один `php`-скрипт который и делает что Вам нужно. Либо, сразу запускаете с ее помощью скрипт, если у Вас преподаватель не указал явно, что все делать только из `php` :)

Comment: раз с симлинком не прошло, можно добавить папку как сетевой диск. там емнип вводятся учетные данные. А потом симлинк на него уже

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то сетевой ресурс нужно смонтировать как диск, а php (скрипт) запускать от имени нужного пользователя.